# Day of week slideshow that can also replace image on hover

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently creating a Wordpress plugin that shows an image and text based on the day of the week with a simple backend function, the only problem is that I'm useless with JQuery.

Basically I want to be able to add buttons under the image from Monday to Sunday where JQuery can swap the days information on click.

Below is a snippet of my php code for Monday. As you can imagine the same code repeats for the rest of the days of the week:

```
//To control the front end
function TimeWidget()
    {
$retset=get_option('timesetting');
            //For weekdays fetching time setting from array $retset
            $mtime=1;
            $ttime=2;   
            $wtime=3;
            $thtime=4;
            $ftime=5;
            $stime=6;
            $sutime=0;
        //fetch Message,Image,url details.
    $fetch_wd=get_option('monday_wd');
            $mtitle=$fetch_wd[mmsgwd];
            $mmessage=$fetch_wd[mmsgwd_m];
            $mimage=$fetch_wd[mimgwd];
            $urlone=$fetch_wd[mlinkwd];
            $minfo1=$fetch_wd[mmsgwd_1];
            $minfo2=$fetch_wd[mmsgwd_2];
            $minfo3=$fetch_wd[mmsgwd_3];

//check if user has not entered any url

        if($urlone=="")
            {
                $urlone=5;
            }

            $today = date('w');
            $widget_title = "Whats on tonight";

                    $monday_fetch = '<div class="ng1_widget_event-text">
                            <div class="ng1_widget_event-text-header">
                            <div class="ng1_widget_event-text-header-top">Monday\'s at NG1 Club</div>
                            <div class="ng1_widget_event-text-header-bottom">'.$mtitle.'</div>
                            </div>
                            <p>'.$mmessage.'</p><span>'.$minfo1.'</span><span>'.$minfo2.'</span><span>'.$minfo3.'</span>
                            <a class="ng1_widget_event-text-link" href="#">Book Online</a>
                            </div>
                            <img src="'.$mimage.'" alt="'.$mtitle.'"></img>';

            echo '<div class="ng1_widget_event">';

        if($mtime == $today) { echo $monday_fetch; $monday_active = ' active'; }

        if($ttime == $today) { echo $tuesday_fetch; $tuesday_active = ' active'; }

        if($wtime == $today) { echo $wednesday_fetch; $wednesday_active = ' active'; }

        if($thtime == $today) { echo $thursday_fetch; $thursday_active = ' active'; }

        if($ftime == $today) { echo $friday_fetch; $friday_active = ' active'; }

        if($stime == $today) { echo $saturday_fetch; $saturday_active = ' active'; }

        if($sutime == $today) { echo $sunday_fetch; $sunday_active = ' active'; }

            // End of Front     
        echo '</div>
            <div class="ng1_widget_event_nights">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="" class="mon_click'.$monday_active.'">Monday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="tue_click'.$tuesday_active.'">Tuesday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="wed_click'.$wednesday_active.'">Wednesday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="thu_click'.$thursday_active.'">Thursday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="fri_click'.$friday_active.'">Friday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="sat_click'.$saturday_active.'">Saturday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="sun_click'.$sunday_active.'">Sunday</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            ';

//end function timewidget()
function widget_myTime(){
?>
```

I'm not asking for the code but guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT:

With the help of below here is my current JS. Would this be the correct way to include JQuery

```
<script>
        var Monday = <?php echo json_encode($monday_fetch); ?>;
        var Tuesday = <?php echo json_encode($tuesday_fetch); ?>;
        var Wednesday = <?php echo json_encode($wednesday_fetch); ?>;
        var Thursday = <?php echo json_encode($thursday_fetch); ?>;
        var Friday = <?php echo json_encode($friday_fetch); ?>;
        var Saturday = <?php echo json_encode($saturday_fetch); ?>;
        var Sunday = <?php echo json_encode($sunday_fetch); ?>;

        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

            $('.ng1_widget_event_nights ul li a').click( function(e) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
                event.stopPropagation(); // stop the click from bubbling
                $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            });

            $( ".mon_click" ).click(function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Monday).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $( ".tue_click" ).click(function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Tuesday).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $( ".wed_click" ).click(function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Wednesday).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $( ".thu_click" ).click(function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Thursday).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $( ".fri_click" ).click(function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Friday).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $( ".sat_click" ).click(function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Saturday).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $( ".sun_click" ).click(function() {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".ng1_widget_event").hide().html(Sunday).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: I would start by looking at the jQuery .click method - http://api.jquery.com/click/ and the .html method - https://api.jquery.com/html/ Using these, you can change the html content of an element upon clicking another.

Comment: I have basic knowledge on creating a simple click event but I don't know how to handle multiple change events, basically I need help with the jQuery structure. Also thank you for your help so far

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change about what you've done? Is it not working, or did you want to simplify it?